# VNC remote desktop - screen is black

Tags: server, gnome, remote-desktop, vnc

My system consists of a laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and a server running Centos 7. I installed tigervnc on the Centos machine, and set it all up for one user to access the machine using Remmina remote desktop. I used the following [guide](https://www.tecmint.com/install-and-configure-vnc-server-in-centos-7/). It works fine for the 1st user I set this up for, but for the second user I set this up for the desktop appears black. Both users have the same configuration with the only changes being the numbering and user credentials in the configuration. I am at a loss why it doesn't work for the second user.

I created the vnc files by login in as the user and running the command:

```
vncserver
```

completed the fields required, after which the required files are created in the user home folder structure. I did this for the 1st and then the second user.

I then copied the file:

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service  /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:2.service
```

Below is the content of the `/home/<username>/.vnc/xstartup` for the second user, note that is exactly the same as the first except for the user credentials:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
gnome-session –session=gnome-classic &
gnome-panel&
```

The content of the `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@\:2.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

# Clean any existing files in /tmp/.X11-unix environment
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l <username> -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1280x1024"
PIDFile=/home/<username>/.vnc/%H%i.pid
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

with `<username>` being replaced with the user login.

I start the vnc process using the following, making sure that I have stopped and disabled the 1st users vnc session:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable vncserver@:2.service
sudo systemctl start vncserver@:2.service
sudo systemctl status vncserver@:2.service
```

with output:

```
● vncserver@:2.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:2.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-02-06 09:44:37 GMT; 6s ago
  Process: 952 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l <username> -c /usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1280x1024 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 947 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || : (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1011 (Xvnc)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-vncserver.slice/vncserver@:2.service
       ‣ 1011 /usr/bin/Xvnc :2 -auth /home/<username>/.Xauthority -desktop venus:2 (<username>) -fp catalogue:/etc/...

Feb 06 09:44:33 venus systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
Feb 06 09:44:37 venus systemd[1]: Started Remote desktop serv
```

the output of the log file `/home/<username>/.vnc/venus\:2.log`:

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.8.0 - built Aug  9 2019 03:04:19
Copyright (C) 1999-2017 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12001000, The X.Org Foundation


Thu Feb  6 09:44:34 2020
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5902
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
/home/<username>/.vnc/xstartup: line 15: gnome-panel: command not found
GLib-GIO-Message: 09:44:37.641: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

** (process:1046): WARNING **: 09:44:37.688: Could not make bus activated clients aware of XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused

Thu Feb  6 09:44:50 2020
 Connections: accepted: 10.0.12.148::59266
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VeNCrypt(19)
 SVeNCrypt:   Client requests security type TLSVnc (258)

Thu Feb  6 09:44:53 2020
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888
 VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 15 (16bpp) little-endian rgb555

Thu Feb  6 09:45:19 2020
 Connections: closed: 10.0.12.148::59266 (Clean disconnection)
 EncodeManager: Framebuffer updates: 1
 EncodeManager:   Tight:
 EncodeManager:     Solid: 1 rects, 1.31072 Mpixels
 EncodeManager:            15 B (1:174763 ratio)
 EncodeManager:   Total: 1 rects, 1.31072 Mpixels
 EncodeManager:          15 B (1:174763 ratio)
 TLS:         TLS session wasn't terminated gracefully
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
```

This bit of the log file seems to be different from the log file created for the 1st user:
`** (process:1046): WARNING **: 09:44:37.688: Could not make bus activated clients aware of XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the solution is to remove the **Anaconda** framework from the  **$PATH** environment variable. So in my case the users `/home/<username>/.bashrc` file needs the following field commented out to look something like:

```
#__conda_setup="$('/home/<username>/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
#if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
#    eval "$__conda_setup"
#else
#    if [ -f "/home/<username>/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
#        . "/home/<username>/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
#    else
#        export PATH="/home/<username>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
#    fi
#fi
#unset __conda_setup
```

Run `source .bashrc`. Remote desktop is then possible. Once the connection is established and you are on the remote desktop, uncomment the above lines and run `source .bashrc` to be able to use **Anaconda** within the remote desktop session.